# Scalability of uPort for millions of users scenarios

Tags: private-blockchain, ipfs, uport

I am currently working on a project using Ethereum, IPFS off-chain storage and uPort for identity management in a private Blockchain.
I fail to find any study/project that analyzes the scalability of uPort with data for scenarios when millions of people need to give some personnal information through uPort. How many servers would be required? How would it scale with data size? Time overhead? etc.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find here an answer for this question (scalability section):
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/351675111_NovidChain_Blockchain-based_privacy-preserving_platform_for_COVID-19_testvaccine_certificates

Comment: It would be nice if you can put a sentence or two about the results, so if the link breaks the answer will still be helpful.